# My BlazorWebAssembly application does not build in AppHarbor

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly, appharbor

I pushed a simple application I made using .NET5 Blazor to the platform AppHarbor.

The problem is that it throws an exception in the build NuGet step and I don't know what is the reason or how to solve it.

The error in question is in attachment:
[image]

Is this related to the platform or something else? Locally I can run the project.

Comment: The error indicates that the required SDK is not available. Your app requires the .NET 5 SDK, but it seems only the .NET Core 3.1 SDK is available. You may need to contact support.

Comment: that maybe the case. Thanks. I will see with the support if they will have any timeframe to have the .NET 5 SDK available.